# Elasticsearch - full insert or partial update

Tags: elasticsearch

In my ELS, I have an index with this structure :

```
_index  "idx"
_type   "ref"
_id "HgyiDUIfiuD"
_source 
    one "24"
    two "45"
    three "OK"
```

I would like insert, or update if *_id* doesn't exist (I set by myself *_id*). But when I update, I want to update all properties except *three*.

I try this but all properties are updated..

```
http://example.com:9200/_bulk

{ "update" : {"_id" : "Cr2LjmQB1KXPTyNjT1hT", "_type" : "ref", "_index" : "idx"} }
{ "doc" : {"one" : "24", "two" : "24", "three" : "OK"} }
```

I tried with "script" object but without success..

Thanks for your answers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found solution by myself

```
http://example.com:9200/_bulk

{"update":{"_index":"idx","_type":"ref","_id":"HgyiDUIfiuD"}}
{"script" : { "source": "ctx._source.one = params.one", "params": {"one" : "13"},  "lang" : "painless"}, "upsert" : {"one" : "13", "two" : "NEW"}}
```

Here, if it is a creation, props *one* et *two* are created with values "13" et "NEW". Else, it is an update with just *one* set to "13"